# Can't seem to link css and js files to index.html in heroku using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

My app.js file looks like this, I am trying to have my root point to a tic tac toe game.

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000))


//serve static files in the public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Process application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: false
}))

// Process application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// Index route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('index.html',{root:"./Tic-Tac-Toe"});


})
```

In my index.html in the ./Tic-Tac-Toe dir, I am linking some files that cannot seem to be found by the server.

```
<link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'ui.css'>
<script src = "jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "ui.js"></script>
<script src = "game.js"></script>
<script src = "ai.js"></script>
<script src = "control.js"></script>
```

I get these errors in my console. [image]

Comment: Can you post your file structure, will be helpful when trying to debug what is happening here

Answer (score 1):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Try above line instead of

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Comment: path is a npm module.

Comment: I added app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); instead of 
app.use(express.static('public')); Did not work.

Comment: I get the same I had before in the console.

Comment: ```<link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = '/ui.css'>
<script src = "/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src = "/ui.js"></script>
<script src = "/game.js"></script>
<script src = "/ai.js"></script>
<script src = "/control.js"></script>```